# Android: GCM server side & sending backwards

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to learn GCM and is currently reading the documentation:

> connection servers take messages from a 3rd-party application server (written by you) and send them to a GCM-enabled Android application (the "client app," also written by you) running on a device.

Now in my other applications that needs a "Larger" amount of data i have done the following steps:

1. Send data to server (HTTP post)
2. Recieve data from server (JSON) (using GSON)

Now as far as i can read from the documentation what this will do is add a middle step which is only usefull if the device i am trying to send to is offline.

my question is:

I am trying to create an instant messaging application, what should i use on my server side? is PHP enough to just instantly send the data to GCM or should i use another server software that can handle these huge chuncks of request, such as Message queue?

Comment: You can only send 4kb with GCM , not so big chunk. For the server part without knowing how many user you expect and your server architecture we can't tell you what's technology is best. But sure PHP can handle few thousand requests

Comment: @grunk so what your saying is i should use the method ive used so far instead of GCM? (it is worth mentioning that i will only send text not pictures nor videos)

Comment: If you don't exceed the 4kb of data , GCM is a good choice (no need to have the app launched nor the phone unlocked to get message).And i'm guessing you currently doing pulling from the phone to the server whereas GCM will push message to the phone instead (battery and datas saves)